# System.getProperty("catalina.base") only for Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina

Does `System.getProperty("catalina.base")` give only the Tomcat home, or does it also work on servers like GlassFish or WebSphere?

`System.getProperty("catalina.base")` gives me the following path:

```
C:\Tomcat 6.0
```

Comment: What is it, the problem you *really* need to solve? You should reformulate the question as such or just ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Only for tomcat. Catalina is a tomcat specific thing!

Catalina is basically the servlet container used by tomcat.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. Is there any way to read property file from outside your web-application

Comment: @Vivek: Ask that as a separate question. (Yes. But let's do this properly by SO rules.)

Comment: In linux many people set the CATALINA_HOME environment variable, so you could read it, but ofcourse thats not a gurantee. In any case, catalina base is just a property passed indicating the location of servlet ocntainer, so if you know wehre you are getting the jvm params, you could work from thereon

Comment: Actually r8 now i m reading property file from Tomcat\conf directory using System.getProperty("catalina.base")
There can be scenario where client may use any other server
That is what my concern is.....

Answer (score 2):

In short, **yes**.

Catalina refers to the Tomcat Servlet Container, the module of the Tomcat Web Application Server that implements the Servlet and JSP Sun Microsystems Specification.

Other modules include Coyote, Jasper and Jasper 2.

The above applies to Tomcat 6. I don't know the details of the latest Tomcat release.